# How to prove $\sum_{i\in I\setminus J} a_i=\sum_{i\in I} a_i-\sum_{i\in I\cap J} a_i$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

Let $I,J$ be finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and $(a_i):\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$

I define $\sum_{i\in I} a_i:=\sum_{k=1}^N a\_i_k$ where $N=|I|$ and $(i_k):\{1,....N\}\to I$ is strictly increasing and onto $I$.

Are the following propositions right? and how can I prove them:

1. "$\sum_{i\in I\setminus J} a_i=\sum_{i\in I} a_i-\sum_{i\in I\cap J} a_i$"
2. "$\sum_{i\in I\cup J} a_i=\sum_{i\in I} a_i+\sum_{i\in J\setminus I} a_i$"
3. "$\sum_{i\in I} a_i=\sum_{i\in I\cap J} a_i+\sum_{i\in I\setminus J} a_i$"

Comment: The claim is definitely false.  Say, $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.  Your claim says that $a_1-a_2=a_1$.

Comment: thank you for your counter example. now i modified the proposition

Comment: @MartinR It isn't *strictly* a question about abstract algebra, but (1) it can trivially be turned into one, and (2) any valid answer will apply equally well to any commutative monoid in place of $\mathbb{R}.$ Therefore,I think the [abstract-algebra] tag was appropriate; but I won't presume to restore it. (You could say that inside this question there's an abstract algebra question struggling to get out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) and (3) are clearly equivalent. But actually the three assertions follow from this property:

> if $E$ and $F$ are disjoint subsets of some set $U$, then $\sum_{i \in E \cup F} a_i = \sum_{i\in E} a_i + \sum_{i \in F} a_i$.

Comment: Thank you. I see it.